# Partial ordering of cv qualifiers vs pointer/reference in template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Say I have a class template with some specializations

```
template<typename T> struct A {};
template<typename T> struct A<T const> {};
template<typename T> struct A<T &> {};
```

Which specialization has the precedence, when I instantiate `A<const int&>`?

I ran a test with GCC, and it picks the `int&` specialization. I assume this is the rule, but I can't find where this is stated.

Edit: I was making a mistake considering that `const int&` matches `const T` for `T=int&`, since templates are more than a mere "macro substitution". In particular, it makes no sense to talk about a const reference (only reference to const). Both the current answers helped me figure it out. Unfortunately, I can only pick one as accepted answer, but thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X&` and `const Y` can’t ever be decompositions of the **same** type, since references can’t be const-qualified.  (Given `using R=T&;`, `const R` is the same type as `R`, but that doesn’t mean that it has that qualifier to match anything.)  As such, no ordering is needed, since the two specializations are disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at what is happening.

#### Statement 1

```
template<typename T> struct A {}; //primary template
```

The above shown statement defines a **primary template**. This means that it can be used for **any type**.

#### Statement 2

```
template<typename T> struct A<T const> {};//specialized for T const
```

The above statement is a **specialization** of the primary template. This means, we are specializing for `T const`. That is, this specialization will be used for template arguments having a **top-level const**.

#### Statement 3

```
template<typename T> struct A<T &> {};//specialized for T&
```

This time we are **specializing** the primary template for template argument of the form `T&`. That is, we are specializing the primary template for lvalue references. Further, the lvalue reference can be a *reference to const* or a *reference to nonconst*. **This means**, this specialization will be used for all lvalue references(both `T&` and `const T&`).

Now lets come back to your question:

> Which specialization has the precedence, when I instantiate A<const int&>?

When we write

```
A<const int&>
```

then since *we already have a speciazation for lvalue references*, that particular speciazation is used as i already explained in statement 3's explanation.

#### Some more examples

```
const int i = 5;
A<decltype(i)> p;//this will use the T const specialization since the template argument has a top level const
```